# DMA7th 1.1 Propositional Logic - Exercise 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Which of these sentences are propositions?

What are the truth values of those that are propositions?

1. Boston is the capital of Massachusetts.
2. Miami is the capital of Florida.
3. $2 + 3 = 5$.
4. $5 + 7 = 10$.
5. $x + 2 = 11$.
6. Answer this question.

Comment: Hint:A proposition is a sentence which is either true or false.

Comment: Hahaha, right away sir! Anything else with that, or shall we just finish your homework asap?

Comment: @barakmanos I am experimenting to see if it is possible to use\abuse stackoverflow as a studygroup platform, where instead of solving questions on your own post it and answer it online to get reviews and insights, and it is backedup by the system, thus via using the right tags you can get it back for revisions :)

Comment: OK, it that you you posted an answer to your on question? I just noticed that... As far as I know, you should post your attempts along with your question, and then ask others to help you with it (or just review it if that is all you need).

Comment: @barakmanos i fear it might get too much downvotes too early! I see that you are a top math.stackexchange, any idea if i can setup stackexchange on my own to use for such purpose? and what you think of the studygroup thing?

Comment: The main problem was your last proposition, which appeared as an instruction to the reader, saying "**answer this question**". I've fixed that now, and retracted my down-vote which was mostly due to that improper interpretation of mine. You should still, post that answer of yours (below) as part of this question IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In logic, a proposition is a contextual declarative statement that is either true or false, but never both.

> a) Boston is the capital of Massachusetts.

Is a proposition; with the truth value True.

> b) Miami is the capital of Florida.

Is a proposition; with the truth value False.

> c) 2 + 3 = 5.

Is a proposition; with the truth value True.

> d) 5 + 7 = 10.

Is a proposition; with the truth value False.

> e) x + 2 = 11.

Is **NOT** a proposition; as its truth value **Unknown**.

> f ) Answer this question.

Is **NOT** a proposition;